# ¿Qué empieza por la letra "F" y se parece a una bombilla?

Tags: vocabulario, hispanoamérica

Hace algunas semanas unos amigos nos prestaron su casa para pasar unos días. En la nevera, vi la chuleta de sonidos iniciales (supongo que alguno de los niños está aprendiendo español). La imagen de la "F" me llamó la atención, ya que es una bombilla. Lo más parecido que se me ocurre que empiece por "F" sería un foco, pero un foco no es más que una luz dirigida.

Dado que estamos en Norteamérica, entiendo que el español que les enseñen en clase va a tener muchas influencias de los países sudamericanos. No sé si es que en alguno de estos países se llama "foco" (u otra cosa que empiece por "F") a la bombilla, o si eso de la tabla es alguna otra cosa.

¿Me saca alguien de dudas, por favor?

[image]

Comment: No hay más que ver que la bandera que han pintado es la de México. :) Por cierto, el sonido "ch" también me tiene totalmente despistado. ¿Es un chile? ¿Y la "y" es un yoyó?

Comment: Para un latinoamericano sería incomprensible que ese dibujo apareciera junto a la letra "b". Generalmente es 'foco'. En Chile es 'ampolleta', mientras que una bombilla es una pajilla para sorber bebidas.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, sí, yo asumí también que eran "chile" y "yoyó" (y que la "W" es [George] Washington). Me llamó también la atención que se enseñen la "ch" y y la "ll", pero supongo que es porque es una tabla de "sonidos iniciales", más que letras, y por eso también se distingue la "g". Claro, que el "sonido inicial" de la "H" tiene un poco de truco...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54409/discussion-on-question-by-diego-adivinanza-empieza-por-la-letra-f-y-se-parece).

Comment: En Colombia no existen bombillas. Son **focos**. En algunos casos también usamos "bombill**o**s"

Comment: Definitivamente F es de foco, esto se debe a que la imagen es de un ejercicio mexicano (por la bandera que esta dada) y que en México no se emplea bombilla sino foco.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el animal que empieza con C (ca, co, cu)? ¿Qué onda con la T?  ¿Tortuga?

Answer (score 4):

Por darte una opción aunque no sea de Sudamérica: ¿podría ser *filamento*?

> [**filamento**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HtcJxSv)
>
> 2. m. Hilo que se pone incandescente en el interior de las bombillas al encenderlas.

Me parecería una palabra un tanto rebuscada para usar como muestra de *f* inicial, eso sí... Por aquí me proponen otras alternativas referentes a la emisión de luz:

- Fuego.
- Faro.

En todo caso, creo que al final tu propuesta de "foco" va a ser la acertada (negritas mías):

> **[foco](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=foco)**
>
> I.    1.  m. **Mx**, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, Pa, Cu, Co:N,O, Ve, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Py,
>   Ar. **Bombilla eléctrica**. ◆ bombillo.

Como la cuestión me intrigó bastante, ya que me fascinan este tipo de diferencias regionales, puse un enlace en Reddit a esta pregunta, y entre los comentarios [podemos leer](https://www.reddit.com/r/mexico/comments/5vx5un/es_muy_com%C3%BAn_en_m%C3%A9xico_usar_la_palabra_foco_m%C3%A1s/):

> El 100% usa el término foco, una bombilla es como la piscina, emparedado o la gaseosa, todo mundo entiende esas palabras pero absolutamente nadie las usa.
>
> Una bombilla es una bomba chiquita.
>
> Si dices bombilla lo primero que pienso es que algo hará explosión, pero en pequeño.

Comment: Es foco, sin duda. Al menos en Argentina, "foco" o "foquito" se usa, además de "bombita", pero lo más común es "lamparita".

Answer (score 1):

¿Podría ser "Farol"? O quizás lo estoy viendo demasiado literal.

> [**farol**](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/farol)
>
> m. Caja de material transparente dentro de la cual se pone una luz: *ha puesto un farol en la terraza del chalé*.

Answer (score 1):

Esa perfectamente se refiere a foco, pero el uso va a depender de donde estés y la cultura.

Por ejemplo en mi país (Venezuela) al foco no se le dice foco sino bombillo, en otros países le dicen bombilla.

Va a depender de la cultura.