# Translation Golf X (Files): The UFO Menace

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

Ya que me tocó elegir el texto, traigo un fragmento de uno de los cuentos de humor absurdo de Woody Allen, *[The UFO Menace](https://www.reddit.com/r/UFOs/comments/2uz87v/the_ufo_menace_woody_allen_1977/)*, que tiene algunas palabrejas complicadas que no se pueden traducir, que yo sepa, con una sola palabra:

> I was in bed at my beach house, but could not sleep because of some fried chicken in the icebox that I felt entitled to. I waited till my wife dropped off, and tiptoed into the kitchen. (...) Suddenly the room turned bright orange. At first, I thought my wife had caught me eating between meals and set fire to the house.

(248 caracteres)

Una propuesta de traducción que no intenta ser sintética sería la siguiente:

> Estaba en la cama, en mi casa de playa, pero no podía dormir porque había un poco de pollo frito en la hielera y me sentía con derecho a consumirlo. Esperé a que mi esposa se durmiera y fui en puntas de pie a la cocina. De repente, la habitación se puso de un color naranja brillante. Al principio, pensé que mi esposa me había pescado comiendo entre comidas y había prendido fuego la casa.

(308 caracteres)

Al igual que en ocasiones anteriores, pueden [consultar las normas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481) y [contar los caracteres](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/).

---

Bueno, nos hemos pasado de fecha y, si bien creo que terminaría de cerrar con las correcciones sugeridas, me parece que se puede dar por ganadora la versión de **@AntonioLópezRuiz**, que, aún con la oración unimembre del comienzo, tiene sentido gramatical. Si todos están de acuerdo con ello, el ganador dispondrá de dos días para presentar un nuevo texto para traducir; pasado dicho lapso, cualquiera podrá hacerlo. ¡Gracias a todos por participar!

Comment: Qué texto tan surrealista :) Nunca había oído [_hielera_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KME5H7O) ni _en puntas_ (en España solemos decir _de puntillas_).

Comment: @fedorqui Tras verificarlo en oxforddictionaries.com, resultó que _icebox_ es un arcaísmo estadounidense por "refrigerador" (o "heladera", "nevera", etc.). Creí que era un refrigerador portátil (tiene su lógica si está en una casa de playa), por eso "hielera".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi respuesta al juego (español mexicano): **157 caracteres**

> Insomne en cama de mi casa playera por desear pollo frito de la nevera. Al dormir mi mujer, sutilmente fui. De pronto, naranja brilló el cuarto. "Me pilló jamando a deshoras e incendió la casa", pensé.

Comment: Interesante propuesta! Me encanta lo de "me cachó". La traducción es de lo más correcta y fiel, pero el "transalation-golf" es un juego que [nos hemos inventado](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591/5481) y tratamos de traducir [usando el menor ´número de caracteres posible](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481).

Comment: Ahhh, no sabía que era un juego de tener menos caracteres. Ahorita se me ocurre alguna

Comment: Te he corregido el conteo de caracteres, dado que para contar solo tenemos en cuenta las vocales y consonantes, no los espacios ni los signos de puntuación. Puedes usar [esta aplicación](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/) para más comodidad.

Comment: Una vez dicho esto debo impugnar esta propuesta para el juego, solicitando al participante que explique el uso de "bufar" para el pollo frito. También solicito al OP que valide la falta de una traducción para "suddenly" o que el participante explique su omisión.

Comment: Bufar: resoplar con fuerza. Usado como el llamado del pollo al personaje. El pollo bufaba, esto es, llamaba incesantemente al personaje y por tanto, se sentía en necesidad de ingerirlo. La omisión de "suddenly" se debe a la inmediatez del acto de encendido de las luces. El omitirlo considero, que no afecta la compresión plena del texto ya qué el lector nota que el evento sucedio de manera repentina sin la necesidad de la palabra. No obstante, si se considera necesario, se puede añadir "De repente" al texto para dar la conotacion requerida. Añadiendo 9 carácteres, para un total de 156.

Comment: Nota: La oración quedaría como: "De repente, el cuarto brilló naranja. "

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, he añadido la información de los comentarios en mi respuesta, así como mi respuesta en caso de que @JMVanPelt decida que la palabra suddenly era necesaria.

Comment: Algunas cosas dignas de señalar son que "arcón" es, por lo que veo, un localismo y se refiere a un congelador de gran tamaño, y no a una mera nevera. También, que lo del pollo que bufa se desvía demasiado del original. Podríamos, al menos, convenir en que el actor sea el narrador y no el pollo, que es el objeto. También se omite adónde fue el personaje. No me parece que se deba omitir el circunstancial que señala lo súbito de la iluminación, no es tan obvio y además indica que sucedió algo inesperado.

Comment: Añado el "sigilmente" por "sigilosamente", del que no encuentro referencias aunque me suena.

Comment: He hecho las modificaciones que me comentas, con ello tengo un total de 159 creo yo. Modifique sigilmente por sutilmente, arcón por nevera y añadí el "suddenly" al texto.

Comment: Lamento la demora, y quedo atento a cualquier cambio que ustedes me indiquen.

Comment: Muy buena sugerencia, la he agregado!

Comment: Como se señaló en otra entrada, "en la nevera" es un circunstancial de lugar y no puede funcionar como modificador indirecto. Para contar los caracteres, usa el enlace que figura en las reglas y en el posteo original.

Comment: He hecho el cambio al que te refieres, con esto creo ya no hay problema. Así mismo utilicé el contador del link. Disculpa tantos errores, es mi primera vez jugando.

Comment: Un par de sutilezas que no son muy esenciales, las señalo pero no quiero pasarme de estricto: puede entenderse que el personaje está insomne y además quiere pollo, y no que lo primero es consecuencia de lo segundo;  el personaje quiere pollo frito (una preparación) y no un pollo frito (un pollo entero, frito); y no se dice adónde va el personaje, aunque si leemos que va a buscar pollo que hay en la nevera, es de suponer que irá a la cocina.

Comment: He hecho los primeros dos cambios requeridos, espero que así quede mejor. No he agregado lo de la cocina dado que considero que se explica por si solo. Pero si quieres puedo modificarlo y añadir "a la cocina" quedando un total de 166 caracteres (tal vez pueda reducirlo, pero no se me ha ocurrido)

Comment: Yo creo que la última frase debería especificas **quién** le pilló jamando. Cierto que no aparecen otros personajes en el fragmento, como por ejemplo la suegra, pero aun así creo que falta un pronombre o algo para completar esa frase, aunque es @JMVanPelt quien debe decidir si falta o no...

Comment: @Diego Me parece que, dado que la mujer es el único otro personaje mencionado y lo breve del fragmento, puede entenderse que se refiere a ella; además, el hecho de que el protagonista fue a por el pollo luego de que su mujer se durmiera puede darnos a entender que era de esperar que ella reaccionara mal si lo descubría (quemando la casa, por ejemplo, que es la gracia del fragmento por lo excesivo y por la naturalidad con la que se lo toma el personaje).

Comment: Para ir cerrando, dos sugerencias: una, poner coma en vez de punto al final de la primera oración; y otra, reemplazar "el cuarto" por "la cocina", que tiene la misma cantidad de caracteres y podría ser una solución a haberla omitido antes.

Answer (score 4):

Comencemos...

## <strike>198 196</strike> 182 caracteres

> Insomne en mi cama de mi casa playera por el ansia de pollo frito de la nevera, esperé el sueño de mi mujer y de puntillas fui a la cocina. De choz todo se tornó naranja: "me ha pillado picando entre horas y ha prendido la casa", pensé.

- [Nevera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QTHQX6V) = frigorífico.
- [De choz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=910Laee) = de repente.
- [Pillar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T0BTFmP) = sobrevenir a alguien algo, cogerlo desprevenido, sorprenderlo (acepción 7); coger, hallar o encontrar a alguien en determinada situación, temple, etc. (acepción 8).

Actualizaciones:

- [Prender](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U2LXouw) = encender fuego (transitivo). Ejemplo del CORDE:

  > *[...] y la persona denunciada por un vecino [...] se ve conminada de pronto, a voces, a salir, y si es que no lo hace se le prende la casa, tirando teas, antorchas, leñas [...].*
  >
  > Alfonso Sastre, "M. S. V. (o La sangre y la ceniza)", 1965 (España).
- Debido → por. *Refactoring* de la segunda frase.

Comment: ¿incendiado → quemado?

Comment: @fedorqui pues no estoy seguro, porque *quemar* implica que el fuego ya ha hecho su efecto, y la casa no estaría naranja sino negra. En cambio *incendiar* es "prender fuego", tras comenzar un incendio es cuando la casa está naranja por la luz de las llamas.

Comment: Bien visto. Se me ocurre _hacer arder_ (o, en este caso, _ella hacía arder_) en tanto que [_arder_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3TgsbT3) significa _sufrir la acción del fuego_.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿y qué tal *prender*?

Comment: Considero que el problema con prender es la ambigüedad generada con las luces. Prender la casa podría hacer llegar al lector a la conclusión de que las luces de la casa fueron prendidas y no forzosamente que la casa se incendiaba.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz es posible, pero el texto está redactado en español de España, y aquí "prender" no se usa con el sentido de "encender las luces" (al menos que yo sepa, no sé si en alguna región concreta se usará así). Puedes comprobarlo con el ejemplo que he puesto del CORDE.

Comment: Es posible que en España se utilice distinto @Carlos Alejo. Honestamente desconozco. Sin embargo, estoy seguro de que en México si se usa de esa manera. Por tanto mi comentario esta sesgado a un español mexicano (como gran parte de mis respuestas). Lo lamento, no pensé que en España se usase distintamente.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz nada que lamentar, amigo. Gran parte de las preguntas de este sitio se basan en las diferencias regionales entre los diversos países hispanohablantes. Te animo a que publiques una pregunta en el sitio sobre el uso del verbo "prender", que puede ser interesante, y así le damos más vida al sitio. No sería la primera vez que un debate en las respuestas de un _translation-golf_ da lugar a nuevas preguntas publicadas.

Comment: "¿Prender las luces se utiliza en el español de España?" ¿Es la pregunta a la cual te refieres?. Honestamente nunca he preguntado, creo sería buena idea iniciar y darle más vida al sitio como comentas.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz además, pasa en todas partes. Fíjate [la que armamos en esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19857/12637) por no saber que en Hispanoamérica se decía "foco" en vez de "bombilla". :-) Y sobre la pregunta, podría ser algo así como "cuál es el sentido principal de 'prender' en los diversos países de habla hispana: ¿enceder una llama o encender una luz?" o algo así, lo que quieras que te clarifique las dudas que puedas tener.

Answer (score 4):

## <strike>211</strike> <strike>191</strike> <strike>189</strike> <strike>178</strike> <strike>169</strike> <strike>165</strike> 161 caracteres

> Encamado en mi casa playera, no dormía ansiando pollo frito de la heladera. Al dormirse mi dama, sigiloso fui a por él. [...] De pronto la sala brilló naranja. Pensé: "Me cazó comiendo a deshora e incendió todo!"

---

[Heladera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K5gdtSU): 6. f. Am. frigorífico (‖ aparato electrodoméstico).

---

Update #2:

- Cambio "pollo frito" por "**ave** frita". Si cuela cuela, cuela. Ciero que un ave es más genérico, pero siendo esto *translation-golf* creo que está dentro de los límites de lo razonable y de las reglas.

Update #3:

- [Desvelar(se)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DXshldX%7CDXtqSSD): uso este verbo para implicar que el protagonista no podía dormir
- Cambio "incendiar la casa" por "incendiar(lo) todo"

Update #4:

- Atendidos comentarios sobre estar en la cama y que la comida es específicamente, pollo.
- Uso "[cazar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=83ExEq7)" en sus sentido de " Sorprender a alguien en un descuido, error o acción que desearía ocultar."
- Uso el recurso de que el personaje cita sus propias palabras/pensamientos en lugar de describir lo que pasaba por su mente.

Update #5:

- Omito el "ella" de "ella me cazó comiendo a deshora..."

Comment: "En la heladera" es un circunstancial de lugar, con lo cual la frase significaría que quien habla deseaba el pollo mientras intentaba dormir dentro de una heladera, o que el pollo se frió en una. Con poner "de" (o "que había en") se soluciona.

Comment: En mi opinión, la palabra ave podría dar al lector la impresión de otro animal frito que buscaba el personaje y no forzosamente el pollo. No obstante, la relevancia de que tipo de ave se deseaba ingerir puede ser baja y por tanto podría el texto acatar las reglas del translation-golf.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz  Tienes toda la razón, podría ser pavo, por ejemplo, pero creo que entra dentro de las licencias del juego. JMVanPelt tiene la última palabra acerca de la validez de "ave" por "pollo" para el juego.

Comment: Tiendo a preferir que diga "pollo", que es lo que dice el original, aunque seguramente lo primero que pensaríamos es que el "ave" es pollo. Lo mismo con la omisión de "I was in bed", ya que si bien a primera vista supondríamos que, si alguien está desvelado, estaría en la cama tratando de dormir, no necesariamente es así.

Comment: Te ha quedado una discordancia en "me cazó comiendo (...) e incendiado todo", así que ganarás un par de caracteres al corregirlo.